# New installation of CentOS -- ssh from the server returns: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic). Why?

Tags: centos, ssl

Centos 6.3.  Brand new installation.  Did ssh-keygen and files are in my ~/.ssh directory.  when I ssh user@1.2.3.4, it returns: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).  I can't find any tutorials laying out why this is. Can you shed some light on the subject?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you sshing *from* and where are you sshing *to*? ssh-keygen needs to be run from the client machine. The private key always stays on that machine, and the public key gets deployed to the system you're connecting to.

Comment: i guess I should rephrase a bit.  I'm trying to ssh from my new installation of CentOS6.2 and it gives me this:

[user1@server1 ~]$ ssh user2@1.2.3.4
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

I can ssh from server2 to server1 with no problems.

Comment: Did you do what I posted? Is 1.2.3.4 server2? The public key from server1 needs to be put in place wherever you're trying to connect to.

Comment: sure did, it seems to be the client side.  what's the best way to de-bug (logs) for looking at this?  (BTW, thanks!)

Comment: Check permissions on the private key. Should've owned by the user, and mode 600.

Comment: yep, I just checked everything and did the process again.  no joy.  It must be an initial configuration or something.

Comment: incidentally, and this is sort of related, should I simply put the same secret key on each server that I want talking to the main one or should I make a separate key on each client using cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys?  thanks again.

Comment: well, the first part of my question was answered inadvertently.  I did a fresh install of CentOS on a different server and did an scp and it worked just right.  So it must have been something in the installation of that other server.  Consider this one solved.... or at least figured out : )